# free, stable and reliable domain name

Tags: web-hosting, domain-name

I have my soft that must connect to a web site and download updates. I use a free web hosting. I must change a hosting because it can work bad, can die etc; a free hosting isn't responsible and reliable. But my soft won't know any changes, it has one address of a web site, and it will connect to that domain all time.

Thereby I need a free domain name that is reliable any time. I can change a hosting all time, and my soft will use one stable domain to connect to a new site.

I have bad experience with co.cc. After I created my free hosting and made a domain for that hosting on co.cc they blocked my account and said that my site (totally empty) is spam :(

Does anybody can suggest me something good?

Thanks!

Comment: You really can't shell out $8/year for your software?

Answer (score 3):

[DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/) has a free tier that will likely meet your needs.